# python 3 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I just started to learn python 3 few months ago, and I having problems in the pycharm IDE... it is very annoying and i wish someone could help to fix that. when I run any code,

**PRINT:**

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00000228 (most recent call first):

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Can you post the code or something? It usually arises when the Python Interpreter is unable to find/import the requested module, which is `encodings` in your case.

Comment: Hey, it's PRINT the same output for any code...